# Any standardized login functionality available in Azure

Tags: authentication, azure

We are looking to host our product on Azure- the intent behind using Azure is that we get to focus on the core product, and are fine with the standard cloud features that Azure offers without needing to understand too much of the internals- not exactly the power users!

One thought was that if Azure had an authentication functionality- profiles, logins, password reset/ reminder etc, it would save us time from building what is essentially a commodity

Any guidance on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure offers the [Access Control Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd582780.aspx), which is a Federated Authentication service. It's already preconfigured with support for Live ID, Google and Yahoo authentication, but you can also add your own security token service (such as ADFS).

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure does not have a built in login feature. However,App Fabric Access Control Service(ACS) [does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee732536.aspx); see the ACS tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706752.aspx) for example usage.